# ansible list docker containers

Tags: linux, docker, ansible

I have a playbook in which one of the tasks gathers info about running docker containers on the specific host.

```yml
- name: Gather info
  hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

   - name: Check all running containers
     become: yes
     command: docker ps --format "{{ \.Names }}"
     register: dkr_ps
  
        
   - debug: msg="{{dkr_ps}}"
```

But somehow the docker cmd run by command module keeps, throwing the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'\\' at 23
  line 1
```

I assume I'm not escaping correctly ?

Comment: Where is `\\` defined? Is that a variable?

Comment: I want to pass the following cmd: `docker ps --format "{{ .Names }}"` but then I have the following error:  ` msg: template error while templating string: unexpected ''.''. String: docker ps --format "{{ .Names }}" ` so I've tried to escape the dot and afterwards I had the error mentioned in the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two conflicting templates: the template expected by the `docker` command, and the Jinja2 templates used in Ansible. Jinja2 is trying to interpret `{{ .Names }}` which isn’t valid; that’s where the error message is coming from.

The general rule of thumb is to escape the Docker template by turning the template symbols into valid Jinja2 expressions:

```
command: docker ps --format "{{ '{{' }} .Names {{ '}}' }}"
```

Comment: Thx a lot Stephen it works now, I totally missed the Jinja part. And it this case do you thing it's better if I replace the current command with `docker ps |  awk '{print $NF}'`. Thing is that I didn't find any ansible module that lists the running containers on a specific machine that's why I've used cmd module, I mean do you thing there's a better way to achieve this ? thx again

Comment: Specifying the output format for `ps` is better than filtering it with AWK, IMO. I don’t know of an appropriate module but I’m not an Ansible expert.

Answer (score 3):

Escape both quotation and braces

```yaml
    - command: 'docker ps --format \"\{\{ .Names \}\}\"'
```

Test it first. For example

```yaml
    - command: 'echo docker ps --format \"\{\{ .Names \}\}\"'
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.cmd|join(' ')
```

gives

```yaml
  result.cmd|join(' '): echo docker ps --format "{{ .Names }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Also possible to use shell command to run following command: sudo docker container ls -a

Another idea:

```
    - name: docker container ls -a
      tags: container_ls
      become: True
      shell:
        "docker container ls -a"
      register: container_info

    - name: docker container ls -a result
      tags: container_ls
      debug:
        msg: "{{container_info.stdout_lines}}"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recently added [docker_ps](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/repo/published/pytoccaz/docker/) module from pytoccaz.docker galaxy collection offers a good solution with a list of dictionaries as output.